# UI feels zoom/magnified after recent UBUNTU 20.04 installation

Tags: drivers, graphics, display, screen, display-resolution

I had recently dual booted my laptop to Ubuntu 20.04. After the installation, the UI feels magnified and zoom than normal. I checked to see if the accesibility>zoom option was enabled but it turns out to be off.
My screen resolution is set to max available i.e 1366 * 768.

Images: [Laptop Display setting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9D9t.png). [Available resolution screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amPtr.png)

Many of the websites that I visit look magnified and zoomed. These websites present me with a vertical scroll bar. The same website using other laptops doesn't present with a vertical scroll bar. Since I had recently installed UBUNTU 20.04. Is there something related to graphics that I have missed out on or any other important installation?
Also in the previous version of UBUNTU 18.04, I had not experienced a similar problem on the same laptop?

Is there any way to solve this zoom and magnified issue? Any help would be welcomed.

Thank you in advance :)

The graphic card detail of my laptop is

> Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)

Comment: Did you try using the resolution **1360x768**. Because that is the perfect resolution on 720p laptop in Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi, @TejasLotlikar I had tried selecting 1360*768, still the result is the same. The weird part is I had selected 1360*768(16:9) and pressed apply button but the tick checkmark is shown a side to its nearest value i.e 1280*720(16:9) but not 1360*768(16:9). Is that expected?

Answer (score 1):

You can also set your resolution through the `xrandr` command
Open up a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> and type `xrandr` You will get a similar output

[image: output of xrandr]

Then see the command structure here

```
xrandr --output MONITOR_ALIAS --mode SUPPORTED_RESOLUTION
```

You will find the **MONITOR_ALIAS** at the location I underlined in red and all **SUPPORTED_RESOLUTION** will be listed below it. Suppose I want to use 1024x768 I will use the command

```
xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --mode 1024x768
```