# X Error of failed request: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg, display-resolution

I have installed Ubuntu 20.10. I have a **HP Elitebook 8570w** with **Nvidia Quadro k1000m** graphics card.

I can't select 1920 x 1080 resolution for my external screen

I have tried:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1920x1080
xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1920x1080
```

But I get this error when I run the second command

```
X Error of failed request: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 
Major opcode of failed request: 140 (RANDR) 
Minor opcode of failed request: 18 (RRAddOutputMode) 
Serial number of failed request: 47 
Current serial number in output stream: 48
```

Comment: You can refer to this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1293582/890892

Comment: @TejasLotlikar Now I get `can't find mode 1920x1080`