# Problem connecting old desktop with Ubuntu 20.04 to LG tv

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr, tv

I installed ubuntu 20.04 to an old Dell Optiflex 755 desktop connected via VGA cable to a **LG 32LD420** tv. With the default resolution 1024x768, the tv display was ok. I tried to configure it to 1920x1080 (60kHz) which is the recommended resolution for this tv using `cvt` and `xrandr` `--newmode` and `--addmode`. When executing the commands from the terminal the screen went black showing a No Signal message. I tried making the change permanent by creating a /etc/profile.d/external_monitor_resol.sh and the display appeared on the tv but distorted, actually it looks compressed horizontally with a black band on the left-hand side, while vertically looks ok (see screenshot). Some extra info:

- When I connect a computer monitor to the pc the display works fine at 1920x1080.
- The tv is not recognized (Settings>Display: Unknown Display).
- The same pc, before installing ubuntu was running Win7 and had no display problem connected to the same LG tv.

Could it be an issue with the parameters of the `xrandr` new `modeline`? Would an upgrade of the tv s/w solve the problem? Can you please help?

[image]

Comment: You can refer to this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1293582/890892

Comment: Thanks @TejasLotlikar, but I am afraid this answer contains the steps I have already followed. My problem is that after I have created and implemented the 1920x1080 resolution the screen is heavily distorted horizontally.